# Vector bundle example in Hatcher

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

In Hatchers notes on K-Theory he gives the following example of a vector bundle that I don't understand. Define $E:=\{(x,v) \in S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \ | \ x \perp v\}$, that is, we regard the inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ restricted to $S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. He then says that one should think of $v$ as a tangent vector $S^n$ but I don't know if that is truly necessary.
He defines $p:E \to S^n, \ (x,v) \mapsto x$ and constructs local trivializations the following way. Choose an $x \in S^n$ and let $U_x \subseteq S^n$ be the open hemisphere containing $x$ and bounded by the hyperplane through the origin orthogonal to $x$. Define $h_x:p^{-1}(U_x) \to U_x \times p^{-1}(x)$ by $h_x(y,v)=(y, \pi_x(v))$ where $\pi_x$ is the orthogonal projection onto the hyperplane $p^{-1}(x)$. Then $h_x$ is a local trivialization since $\pi_x$ restricts to an isomorphism of $p^{-1}(y)$ onto $p^{-1}(x)$ for each $y \in U_x$.

$(1)$ By open hemisphere he means the subset of $S^n$ where the last coordinate is greater than $0$ right? Why is this necessary and why do we not regard the entire hemisphere?

$(2)$ If $n=2$ and $x=(0,0,1)$, then the hyperplane is the $xy$-plane, so nothing changes when restricting the open hemisphere and $U_x$ is simply the open hemisphere, right? So when moving $x$ on $S^2$ it just tilts the hyperplane by the same angle and thus "cuts off" a bit of the open hemisphere, doesn't it?

$(3)$ When defining $h_x$ we have $p^{-1}(U_x)=U_x \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and one regards $\pi_x: p^{-1}(x) \bigoplus p^{-1}(x)^{\perp} \to p^{-1}(x),$ where $p^{-1}(x) \bigoplus p^{-1}(x)^{\perp}=S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}.$ Why is $p^{-1}(x)$ a hyperplane?

$(4)$ Why does $\pi_x$ restrict to an isomorphism?

Comment: For (1), because you need to work with *open* sets.  And your interpretation isn't quite right:  the open hemisphere will change as $x$ changes, so it need not be just $x_{n+1}=0$.

Comment: @Randall Ah of course! So when he says that its bounded by the hyperplane, it should also mean that the points on the plane itself are not part of $U_x$ but only up to that plane, because otherwise its not guaranteed to be open, right?

Comment: The inner product is a  bilinear map $\mathbb R^{n+1} \times \mathbb R^{n+1} \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @PaulFrost But we regard a subset of $S^n \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, so we have to regard the inner product on the added dimension, don't we?

Comment: No, we have to take the standard inner product on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Of course we have $\mathbb R^{n+1} \times \mathbb R^{n+1} = \mathbb R^{2n+2}$, but this is irrelevant for the purpose of the question.

Comment: @PaulFrost Ah yes, I made a silly mistake, now I see it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) No. Given $x \in S^n$, he considers the hyperplane through the origin orthogonal to $x$. This is the $n$-dimensional linear subspace
$$E_x = \{ v \in \mathbb R^{n+1} \mid \langle v, x \rangle = 0 \} \subset  \mathbb R^{n+1} . \tag{1}$$
Note that
$$E= \bigcup_{x \in S^n} \{x\} \times E_x . \tag{2}$$
$E_x$ separates $S^n$ into the two disjoint open hemispheres
$$H_x^\pm = \{ v \in S^n \mid \pm \langle v, x \rangle > 0 \} .\tag{3}$$
We have $x \in H_x^+$. Thus the open hemisphere containing $x$ and bounded by the hyperplane $E_x$ is the set $U_x = H_x^+$.

(2) First question: $U_x$ is the upper open hemisphere $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in S^2 \mid x_3 > 0\}$. Second question: No. If we move $x$, then $U_x$ is dragged along with $x$. For example, if $x = (1,0,0)$, then $U_x = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in S^2 \mid x_1 > 0\}$.

(3) By $(2)$ and the definiton of $p : E \to S^n$ we have for $x \in S^n$
$$p^{-1}(x) = \{x\} \times E_x . \tag{4}$$
Hatcher identifies $\{x\} \times E_x$ with $E_x$. When he speaks about the orthogonal projection onto the hyperplane $p^{-1}(x)$ he means the linear map
$$\pi_x : \mathbb R^{n+1} \to E_x, \pi_x(v) =  v - \langle v, x \rangle x.$$
Note that

1. $\pi_x(v) \in E_x$ because $\langle \pi_x(v),x \rangle = \langle v, x \rangle - \langle v, x \rangle \langle x, x \rangle = 0$ (since $\langle x, x \rangle = \lVert x \rVert^2 = 1$ for $x \in S^n$).
2. $\pi_x(v) = v$ for $v \in E_x$ because in that case $\langle v, x \rangle = 0$.
3. $\ker \pi_x = Span(x)$ = one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ spanned by $x$. In fact, $v \in \ker \pi_x$ means that $v = \langle v, x \rangle x \in Span(x)$ and $v = \lambda x$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ gives $\pi_x(v) = \lambda x - \langle  \lambda x, x \rangle x = \lambda x - \lambda  \lVert x \rVert^2 x = 0$.

The proper definition of $h_x$ is then
$$h_x : p^{-1}(U_x)  \to U_x \times E_x, h_x(y,v) = (y,\pi_x(v)) .$$

(4) The claim is that for each $y \in U_x$ we get an isomorphism
$$h_{x,y} : p^{-1}(y) = \{y\} \times E_y \stackrel{h_x}{\to} \{y\} \times E_x .$$
This means that the restriction
$$\pi_{x,y} :  E_y \stackrel{\pi_x}{\to} E_x $$
is an isomorphism of vector spaces. Since $E_y, E_x$ are both $n$-dimensional, it suffices to show that it is surjective. Consider the equation
$$w = v - \langle v, x \rangle x .\tag{5}$$
We have to find a solution $v \in E_y$ (which means $\langle v, y \rangle = 0$). Applying the scalar product with $y$ to $(5)$, we get
$$\langle w, y \rangle = -\langle v, x \rangle \langle x, y \rangle$$
and therefore
$$\langle v, x \rangle = - \frac{\langle w, y \rangle}{\langle x, y \rangle} .$$
This gives
$$v = w - \frac{\langle w, y \rangle}{\langle x, y \rangle}x . \tag{6}$$
Defining
$$\rho_{x,y} : E_x \to E_y, \rho(w) = w - \frac{\langle w, y \rangle}{\langle x, y \rangle}x , \tag{7}$$
we see that
$$\pi_{x,y} \circ  \rho_{x,y} = id .\tag{8}$$
This can of course be verified directly without solving $(5)$. If you want, you can also verify that $\rho_{x,y} \circ  \pi_{x,y} = id$, but it is unnecessary.

By the way, we can now easily see that $h_x$ is a homeomorphism. Its inverse is given by
$$h^{-1}_x(y,w) = (y,\rho_{x,y}(w)) = (y,  w - \frac{\langle w, y \rangle}{\langle x, y \rangle}x)$$
which is obviously continuous.

*Remark.*

To clear doubts about domain and range of $h_x$, let us summarize what we did above.

1. $p^{-1}(U_x)$ is a subpace of $U_x \times \mathbb R^{n+1}$.
2. The map $H_x : U_x \times \mathbb R^{n+1} \to U_x \times E_x, H_x(y,v) = (y, v - \langle v, x \rangle x) = (y, \pi_x(v))$, is well-defined and continuous.
3. $h_x = H_x \mid_{p^{-1}(U_x)} : p^{-1}(U_x) \to U_x \times E_x$, is well-defined and continuous.
4. The map $\bar \rho_x : U_x \times E_x \to U_x \times \mathbb R^{n+1}, \bar \rho_x(y,w) = (y, w - \frac{\langle w, y \rangle}{\langle x, y \rangle}x)$, is well-defined and continuous. Since $\langle w - \frac{\langle w, y \rangle}{\langle x, y \rangle}x, y \rangle =0$, we have $w - \frac{\langle w, y \rangle}{\langle x, y \rangle}x \in E_y$. Therefore $\bar \rho_x ( U_x \times E_x) \subset p^{-1}(U_x)$.
5. $\rho_x :  U_x \times E_x \stackrel{\bar \rho_x}{\to} p^{-1}(U_x)$, is well-defined and continuous.
6. $\rho_x \circ h_x = id$ and $h_x \circ \rho_x = id$. Hence $h_x$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: There are a couple of points I don't understand in your answer. $(1)$ Could you give some insights how you came up with these sets? I appear to lack knowledge here and appear to have no real idea why this is what he meant. $(2)$ So basically my mistake here was that nothing is cut off but rather the whole $U_x$ is just tilted by same angle that $x$ is rotated by, right? $(3)$ I dont understand what your $p:D \to S^n$ is here.

Comment: (1) Which sets do you mean? (2) Yes. Draw a picture for $n = 1$ to see what is going on. (3) $D$ was a typo.

Comment: $(1)$ I mean $E_x$ and the $H_x$. $(3)$ Ah I also made a mistake in my question and wrote $B$ instead of $S^n$... Now I realize another mistake, I am making a lot of silly mistakes I am sorry. I thought that $p^{-1}(x)$ is $\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ but obviously that is not the case, since $E$ is defined to be a specific subset.

Comment: $E_x$ is the **definition** of hyperplane through the origin orthogonal to $x$.  The $H_x^\pm$ are the hemispheres "above" and "below" this hyperplane. Take $n=1$ to visualize this.

Comment: Do you know a book that covers this definition? I should go read about it.

Comment: You shoud consult a book on linear algebra dealing especially with inner products. But I cannot give a recommendation, for almost half a century I never looked into such a book.

Comment: Im sorry to bother you again, but shouldn't $x \in H_x^-$ instead of $x \in H_x^+$? Because $\langle x, x \rangle= ||x||^2.$ So $U_x$ should be $H_x^-$, shouldn't it?

Comment: I also think your $H_x^{\pm}$ needs to be $\{v \in S^n \ | \pm \langle v,x \rangle > 0\}$. This would also fix what I mentioned earlier. I think that the bijectivity of $\pi_x,y$ translates to $h_x$ and $h_x$ is continuous, however, how can you conclude that $h_x$ is a homeomorphism?

Comment: @user3118 You are right. I corrected the definition of $H_x^\pm$. All linear maps are continouus, thus each linear isomorphism is a homeomorphism because its inverse is linear.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Is it possible to write down the inverse in this case explicitly as well?

Comment: @user3118 I do not see an explicit formula for the inverse. But this does not mean that no such formula exists.

Comment: When going over some details I stumbled across the following. You mentioned that one can use that $h_x$ is linear, however, what is the vector space strucure on $\pi^{-1}(U_x)?$ As far as I can tell, this is the set $\{(y,v) \in U_x \times \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \vert y \perp v\}$ which is not a linear subspace, is it? Without this we can't conclude that $h_x$ is linear.

Comment: @user3118 $E_x$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and $p^{-1}(x) = \{x\} \times E_x$ gets the structure of a vector space by $(x.v)+(x,w) = (x,v+w), \lambda (x,v) = (x,\lambda v)$. In other words, it is the unique structure of a vector space such that the canonical bijection $b_x : p^{-1}(x) \to E_x , b_x(x,v) =v$, becomes an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, but my question was why $\pi^{-1}(U_x)$ becomes a vector space. I don't see why that is the case.

Comment: @user3118 Okay, I didn't read your comment properly. Actually only the $h_{x,y}$ are homeomorphims by linearity. But this does not automatically imply that $h_x$ is a homeomorphism. Hatcher did not prove it when he gave the example. Either you can explicitly determine an inverse (which I do not see) or you have to use Lemma 1.1.

Comment: Ah okay. Looking at Lemma 1.1, it is a lemma about isomorphisms of vector bundles, but I am trying to prove that $h_x$ is a local trivialization. Can I still use it here? I will need to work out the details if that is the case.

Comment: @user3118 You are right, using Lemma 1.1 would be circular. But see my update.

Comment: Ok, that looks good to me, thanks. At first I was a bit sceptical because the $\ro_x,y$ dont match the domain and range of the $h_x$ but if you adapt $y$ in the way you did it should work out. Could you explain how you went from the line above $(6)$ to equation $(6)$?

Comment: @user3118 Insert the expression in the line above $(6)$ into $(5)$: this gives equation $(6)$. I also made a final update of my answer.